# Is there a temporal reward in Casper, that the earlier you place bets, the more you are rewarded?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, consensus, casper, reward

In Casper, the consensus-by-bet proof-of-stake system, is there a temporal reward, that the earlier you place bets, the more you are rewarded?